# How can I auto run a JS function when a condition is met using JQuery without error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically my issue is I am trying to make a calculator that auto updates itself while the user is typing.

My main issue is, for whatever reason, I just cannot get my code to work correctly.

The way that I went about this is to use the following code below:

```
      $(function() {
        $('#value').keyup(function (e)  {    
        if($(this).val().length >= 5)
        return sub();
        }) 
      });
```

But I keep getting the error:

> **"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at index.html:40"**

Here is the index HTML. Return sub is in an external JS file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="icon.png">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  </head>
    <body>
        <div action="#">
            <p>
                <label style="text-align:center;" for="valuename"><img id=img src="rs.png"> Value</label>
                <input id="value" name="valuename" type="tel">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label style="text-align:center;" for="valueprice">Buy Price</label>
                <input id="price" name="valueprice" type="number">
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
            <div id="results1">
                Get:<img id=img src="rs.png"><b style="color:green;text-align:right" id="keep"></b>
                <br> Price <b style="color:green;">$</b><b style="color:green;" id="keeprate"></b></br>
            </div>
            <div id="results2">
                Sell:<img id=img src="rs.png"><b style="color:green;" id="sell"></b>
                <br> Earn <b style="color:green;">$</b><b style="color:green;text-align:right" id="profit"></br>
  </div>
  <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#value').keyup(function (e)  {    
        if($(this).val().length >= 2)
        return sub();
        }) 
      }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am completely stuck and pulling my hair out over here, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: to begin with you need to close the `link` on this line `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="icon.png"`

Comment: <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="icon.png" need to be like this <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="icon.png">

Comment: Also this is not valid `$('value')` try using `$('#value')`, Also PLEASE note that you should never have multiple elements with the same id `id=img`

Comment: I think there is an issue with the cdn, try replacing with this `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: when targetting something with jquery by id you need to add # before the name, `$('#yourId')`

Comment: you need to add # before the name of id(value) ex:- $('#value)

Comment: did you try to update the CDN to the link I provided above, and then you will need to follow @gavgrif answer below

Comment: Ok yes, sorry for the confusion. I actually did have the #value on the live site. For some reason I must have erased it by accident. Although this still hasn't solved my issue unfortunately.

Comment: Paul Fitzgerald Thanks a ton! This was the issue! Please post as an answer so I can accept. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with the `cdn` that you are using, leading to the error `$ is not defined`.

If you update the cdn to use the following it should work.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This was the issue! Thanks so very much.

Answer (score 2):

You need the id of the "value" input - otherwise you will not be targetting the input with the query.

Change this

```
$('value').keyup(function (e)  { ...
```

to this

```
$('#value').keyup(function (e)  { ...
```

Comment: you are correct with the this, but the error he is seeing seems to actually be something different -  `"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at index.html:40"` which is why I think it's a CDN issue

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald - and your comment in the comments sectionwould address this- but that would only shitft hte issue to the error that I saw - so i chose not to re-state your comment as a solution and focussed on the new alternate issue to helpe he OP.

Comment: The CDN was the issue, for some reason the # was missing too but was there on the live version of the code. I must have erased it by accident. Much appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks and Suggest you invite  Paul Fitzgerald to provide that as a solution - os that you can mark it as the correct solution that resolved your issue. Unfortunately you cannot select a comment as the solution sand good work should be rewarded.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see.

1. You used these lines of code to get it work:

```
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#value').keyup(function (e)  {    
        if($(this).val().length >= 2)
        return sub();
        }) 
      }); 
    </script>
```

2. That is correct and It **should work** and the Error

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at index.html:40"

you get **because of CDN failure**. Yes it is rare case but CDN can fail and basically Google did not provide jQuery library that is why  **$ is not defined**

3. To avoid this and not rely on CDN you can download jQuery yourself [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js)

and insert it before your scripts.js external file  like this or example:

```
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

This way you have **jQuery first** and it is **executed first** so your js code that relies on it can use it. So no need to use this anymore in html if you will

```
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#value').keyup(function (e)  {    
        if($(this).val().length >= 2)
        return sub();
        }) 
      }); 
    </script>
```

4. Paul Fitzgerald mentioned that you need to close (... />) `<link> tag` but it is not correct. It should work just fine in my opinion.
5. As a recommendation

   - Try to avoid (or combine) using CDNs because you rely on a third-party and if CDN fails your code can not work.
   - Place your javascript code before BODY closing tag. There are plenty of techniques where to place your JS code and how to serve it from a server but it is another story.

Answer (score -1):

The id.. you have to take the input id
$("value") WRONG
$("#value") RIGHT